# HTML, CSS Optimizing page with too many images on it

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have created some Restaurant website, that's got single Menu page containing different food items. The problem is that above mentioned page is loading too slow on first load. Firstly, i thought that when u enter the Menu page, all items with appropriate images (about 200 images) are loading and this is the root cause of the problem, but then i set up JS trigger which clicks certain menu-item on page-load and loads only 6 images. However, it didn't help. So please, describe some ways of optimizing my page for fast loading.

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: What should be optimized? There's no code to optimize in the post.

Comment: @Teemu I mean, any ways to avoid images loading. I cannot post code, cuz it is too large and inappropriate.

Comment: As you can see, without the code we can only speculate what could be wrong. You have to do your own research to narrow down the code. E.g. remove scripts untill the page loads faster, that way you'll find the script which is slowing your page. If all the scripts are removed, and the page is still slow, remove other source links (like CSS stylesheets), at some point you'll find out the cause.

Comment: @Teemu Well, i ll try that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if only 6 images are loaded, depending on the size of the images, it'll be slow.
COnsider resize your images to optimize the speed.

You can do it using Gimp / Photoshop or this website: https://tinypng.com

[EDIT]

Don't use all these separated files in Production:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-lightbox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo_themes/default/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hover-min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

- the CSS inside the HTML

And do you really need THAT many JS files?

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/isotope.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/nivo-lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Don't use in this way, minify all and be sure that you are using the minified version of jquery, not the jquery.js.

Check it here: https://code.jquery.com/

Give a try to Grunt to help you with the automation and minification of the code: https://gruntjs.com/

Or just use this website: https://www.minifier.org/

Comment: Each of 6 images weighs approx. 80 KB, is it sufficient to slow the loading?

Comment: What's the website? Is it online? Something else is making it worse. Post your code here or in a CodePen link

Comment: alfreda.com.az - Go to the menu on nav, click any item

Comment: Your are calling too many CSS files and JS libraries. Try to minify it all and put in one only/

Answer (score 0):

You should optimize you all images:
You can use online tool for this:
`Compress jpeg`
url : `https://compressjpeg.com/`

`Compress png`
url: `https://compresspng.com/`

You can upload many picture on it and this will zip folder of compress images.

After optimize all images you site speed will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Use java script ajax and create pagination for listing. i.e you will get data from database and display only 10 values at once. and for images.. pick some of your common images and create sprite .. these 2 things help you the most. in your every single project..